# Post preview and oembed provider issue using polylang plugin with subdomains

Tags: posts, subdomains, oembed, previews

- [ X ] I have searched for similar issues in both open and closed tickets and cannot find a duplicate.
- [ X ] The issue still exists against the latest `master` branch of Polylang and the latest WordPress version.
- [ X ] This bug happens with only Polylang plugin active
- [ X ] This bug happens with a default WordPress theme active
- [ X ] I can reproduce this bug consistently

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Ubuntu 20.04 + nginx + mysql 8 + latest woordpress + permalinks + subdomain + polylang with subdomain option + cloudflare dns proxy

1.2. Open WP dashboard at domain.com -> add new post for the language your subdomain.domain.com is at -> *write something* in the post -> preview -> open in new tab

1.3. You are taken to subdomain.domain.com/p=2342, where in turn you are greeted with a WP 404 page not found. The preview has been generated at domain.com/p=2342. You are able to access the preview, by typing the domain.com/p=2342 manually.

2. Ubuntu 20.04 + nginx + mysql 8 + latest woordpress + permalinks + subdomain + polylang with subdomain option

2.2. Open WP dashboard at domain.com -> add new post for the language your subdomain.domain.com is at

2.3. Paste a link of subdomain.domain.com/any-post-link-url-encoded-transliteration

2.4. The woordpress link generator can't process the link of the subdomain.domain.com/any-post-link-url-encoded-transliteration and receive a metainfo about the post

### Expected behavior and actual behavior

1. Post preview link takes to subdomain.domain.com instead of domain.com, where the link is generated.
2. for the oembed link to open a modal showing the usual picture and metainfo about the post from the subdomain.domain.com site, while writing a post.

Any guidance would be very appriciated.

I didn't find anything related to this issue nor on stackoverflow, nor on woordpress, nor here among issues, nor polylang github.
I have searched through all the posts in all the places polylang listed on their github readme, also.

### What I have already tried to solve your issue

1. Preview link
   1.1. unsuccessful nginx, .htaccess and php header rewrites

1.2. nginx proxy for subdomain.domain.com to domain.com

1.3. expanding server_name directive with the subdomain.domain.com in a nginx server block

1.4. unsuccessful attempts at finding of the url creator/initiator function in wp-admin, wp-includes and wp-content folders. All of them returned domain.com, so I don't know where and how the redirect link is chosen.

1.5. serving subdomain.domain.com and domain.com in seperate nginx server blocks

1.6. in wp dashboard -> language -> settings -> url modification -> switching between subdomain option, vs custom domains -> entering the same domains. Everything stays the same, but still both issues remain.

2. Oembed
   2.1. Added a oembed provider in functions.php `wp_oembed_add_provider( 'https://subdomain.domain.com/*', 'https://domain.com/oembed/', false );`

2.2.
[image]

2.3. The endpoint at which the oembed is requested from the new post frontend is https://rutest.mainampasauli.news/wp-json/oembed/1.0/proxy?url=https://rutest.mainampasauli.news/hukuygiuygiuyg/&lang=ru&_locale=user  So I tried a couple of urlencoded and regular permutations with this request. Unsuccessful.

Thank you. Any help would be very appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues on our website, not using cache plugin resolved some of the issues, like not getting 404 when clicked Preview changes but from allready published page, from Draft, Preview changes still gives 404. Also the server responds with 404 for generated dynamic CSS for second language(which is subdomain) and after 20min the error is gone and it CSS is loaded, again not using cache plugin resolves this issue.
I still havent found full solution for this problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255721)